# Best replacement for WLP545

Tags: yeast

Question: what is the best alternative to use instead of White labs yeast WLP545, in order to get the most similar result? Or is there any commercial produced beer using WLP545 that you can grew a culture from?

Background: We have a Belgian style IPA fermentera with WLP545 that we want to bring to a homebrewing competition, we need to brew it in the next couple of weeks but for some reason White Labs have paused their production of WLP545.

Comment: Wyeast doesn't make WLP545. WLP545 is a White labs product.  Are you looking for a wyeast substitute or a white labs substitute?

Comment: Ofcource, thanks brewchez, I updated the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.wyeastlab.com/rw_yeaststrain_detail.cfm?ID=136

Wyeast Adrennes seems to be the best bet.

Did you save the yeast trub from the WLP545 brew?

Comment: No we didnt save the trub, there isnt even any bottles left, looks like were going for your suggestion, thanks!